# update query returns 0 affected rows

Tags: mysql

I want to update a table called vm_elements. I have 2 columns in that physical stock and transit quantity. To update those columns i am using update query. It returns output correctly but doesn't reflect database columns.

Code:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM vm_elements';
$result=mysqli_query($link,$sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
    $Quantity1=$_POST['p_'.$row['skuID'].'_q1'];
    $Quantity2=$_POST['p_'.$row['skuID'].'_q1'];
    $id=$row['skuID'];
    //mysqli_query($link, "update vm_elements SET physicalStock='$Quantity1', transitQuantity='$Quantity2' WHERE id='$id'");

    //echo "update vm_elements SET physicalStock='$Quantity1', transitQuantity='$Quantity2' WHERE id='$id'";


    $query="update vm_elements SET physicalStock='$Quantity1', transitQuantity='$Quantity2' WHERE id='$id'";

    if(mysqli_query($link, $query))
    {
        echo "Records added successfully.";
    } 
    else
    {
        echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
    }
}
```

Can you please tell me what has done wrong? I am stuck really bad

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: Try and get out of the habit of declaring SQL statements in throw-away variables that are used only once. It's a lot easier to follow code where the query is supplied directly to the function, and there's no longer a chance of messing up and sending in `$sql3` instead of the visually similar `$sql8`.

Comment: @skk mind sharing the table structure? Could it be the column `skuID` does not exist?

Answer (score 0):

Remember, unless your operation makes changes you will not get any "affected rows". If you're updating with values that are identical to what's already in the table the result should be 0 rows affected.

A query may return 0 or more "affected rows", or it might return an error. You'll need to test for these two conditions separately if you're concerned about an update being applied because it *should* make changes.

Comment: i checked it returns 0 affected rows

Comment: That means your query ran successfully, it simply didn't change anything. You may need to manually zero out your columns to see if changes get applied, or try using different values.

Comment: actually i am trying to update previous values with newer one

Comment: One thing I can see is in your query you reference the `id` column, but the key you're basing that off of is called `skuID` which could be different. You'll want to check that you're pulling the correct value and matching it to the correct column.

Comment: Yes, But now i have changed column ref id with SKUID. but still i am getting same error. 0 rows afftected